# ssis import excel to database with derived column

Tags: import, ssis, derived

I tried to use SSIS 2015 to import an excel into sql server database, with the value of one column updated. for example,

```
aaa_123 ---> 123
bbb_123 ---> 123
ccc_123 ---> 123
```

How can i write the expression in the derived column?

Answer (score 1):

The expression four your derived column will be

```
TOKEN(YourColumn, "_", 2)
```

This will take the second "token" from an input string where the "tokens" (parts of the string) are separated by the `_` character.